# Tricky list transformation in Haskell

Tags: haskell

The first list has length 27, I want to transform this into a list of length 9 such that the list indexes are combined as shown in the second list below:

```
[[Just 3,Just 6,Nothing],[Nothing,Just 7,Just 1],[Just 2,Nothing,Nothing]
,[Nothing,Just 5,Nothing],[Nothing,Nothing,Nothing],[Just 1,Just 8,Nothing]
,[Nothing,Nothing,Just 9],[Just 2,Nothing,Just 4],[Just 7,Nothing,Nothing]
,[Nothing,Nothing,Nothing],[Nothing,Just 1,Just 3],[Nothing,Just 2,Just 8]
,[Just 4,Nothing,Nothing],[Just 5,Nothing,Just 2],[Nothing,Nothing,Just 9]
,[Just 2,Just 7,Nothing],[Just 4,Just 6,Nothing],[Nothing,Nothing,Nothing]
,[Nothing,Nothing,Just 5],[Just 3,Nothing,Just 8],[Just 9,Nothing,Nothing]
,[Nothing,Just 8,Just 3],[Nothing,Nothing,Nothing],[Nothing,Just 6,Nothing]
,[Nothing,Nothing,Just 7],[Just 6,Just 9,Nothing],[Nothing,Just 4,Just 3]]

[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]
,[10,13,16],[11,14,17],[12,16,18]
,[19,22,25],[20,23,26],[21,24,27]
```

What would be the simplest sulution to this problem?

I have been trying to use `foldr`but I just can figure out how to have each element put in a different list depending on the index, there is a clear pattern in how the data is combined so there must be some simple solution that exploits this pattern...

Comment: What is the procedure to get the second list from the first?

Comment: It is entirely unclear to me what this function should actually do from 1 input-output. If you have a solution but are looking for a simpler one, you should include the existing solution. If you don't have a solution, you should included your attempts. You should also include an english language description of what the function does.

Comment: Look at jamshidh answer that is exactly what i want to do but was looking for a more general solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
import Data.List

chunksOf :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunksOf n [] = []
chunksOf n xs =
  let (ys,zs) = splitAt n xs in ys : chunksOf n zs

regroup: [a] -> [[[a]]]
regroup = transpose $ map (chunksOf 3) $ transpose $ chunksOf 3 xs
```

For example, `concat $ regroup [1..27]` gives you the second matrix.

Comment: That is it, extremely nice! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want super simple, and if this isn't part of a larger pattern (ie- you need this to work for NxN matrices), just do this.

```
f [x1,x2,x3,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,
   x11,x12,x13,x14,x15,x16,x17,x18,x19,x20,
   x21,x22,x23,x24,x25,x26,x27] = 
      [[x1,x4,x7],[x2,x5,x8],[x3,x6,x9]
      ,[x10,x13,x16],[x11,x14,x17],[x12,x16,x18]
      ,[x19,x22,x25],[x20,x23,x26],[x21,x24,x27]]
```